# Meaning of L+k-1 index in Quickselect algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am studying quickselect for a midterm in my algorithms analysis course and the algorithm I have been working with is the following:

```
Quickselect(A[L...R],k)
// Input: Array indexed from 0 to n-1 and an index of the kth smallest element
// Output: Value of the kth position 
s = LomutoPartition(A[L...R]) // works by taking the first index and value as the 
                              // pivot and returns it's index in the sorted position
if(s == k-1) // we have our k-th element, it's k-1 because arrays are 0-indexed
    return A[s]
else if(s> L+k-1) // this is my question below 
    Quickselect(L...s-1,k) // basically the element we want is somewhere to the left 
                           // of our pivot so we search that side 
else
    Quickselect(s+1...R, k-1-s) 
    /* the element we want is greater than our pivot so we search the right-side 
     * however if we do we must scale the k-th position accordingly by removing 
     * 1 and s so that the new value will not push the sub array out of bounds 
     */
```

My question is why in the first if do we need `L + k - 1`? Doing a few examples on paper I have come to the conclusion that no matter the context L is always an index and that index is always 0. Which does nothing for the algorithm right?

Comment: L will become different from 0 with the recursive call you have at the end (s+1).

Comment: I don't understand.  Can you do a short example?

Comment: Work out this example: `A = [2, 1, 3, 5, 4], L = 0, R = 4, k = 4`. Then `s = 1` and control will flow into the final `else` block with `Quickselect(A, L=2, R=4, k=2)`... so at that moment `L > 0` in the recursive call.

Comment: Ok so if `k = 4` then `k-1 = 3` so I want the element in the `3rd position`. Partitioning 2 leaves me with `A = [1,2,3,5,4]` because `s = 1` and `1 < 3` I call `Quickselect(2..4, 1)`yielding the solution of `3`. And in the second iteration `L = 2` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a discrepancy between the line

```
if(s == k-1)
```

and the line

```
else if(s> L+k-1)
```

The interpretations are incompatible.

As Trincot correctly notes, from the second recursive call on, it's possible that *L* is not 0. Your Lomuto subroutine doesn't take an array, a low index, and a high index (as [the one in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme) does, for example). Instead it just takes an array (which happens to be a subarray between low and hight of some other array). The index *s* it returns is thus relative to the subarray, and to translate it to the position within the original array, you need to add *L*. This is consistent with your first line, except that the line following it should read

```
return A[L + s]
```

Your second line should therefore also compare to *k - 1*, not *L + k - 1*.

---

**Edit**

Following the comment, here is the pseudo-code from Wikipedia:

```
// Returns the n-th smallest element of list within left..right inclusive
// (i.e. left <= n <= right).
// The search space within the array is changing for each round - but the list
// is still the same size. Thus, n does not need to be updated with each round.
function select(list, left, right, n)
    if left = right        // If the list contains only one element,
        return list[left]  // return that element
    pivotIndex  := ...     // select a pivotIndex between left and right,
                        // e.g., left + floor(rand() % (right - left + 1))
    pivotIndex  := partition(list, left, right, pivotIndex)
    // The pivot is in its final sorted position
    if n = pivotIndex
        return list[n]
    else if n < pivotIndex
        return select(list, left, pivotIndex - 1, n)
    else
        return select(list, pivotIndex + 1, right, n)
```

Note the conditions

```
        if n = pivotIndex
```

and

```
        else if n < pivotIndex
```

which are consistent in their interpretation of the indexing returned in partitioning.

Once again, it's possible to define the partitioning sub-routine either as returning the index relative to the start of the sub-array, or as returning the index relative to the original array, but there must be consistency in this.

Comment: Hmmm the algorithm is given in my textbook `Introduction to the design and analysis of algorithms by Anany Levitin` I even double checked how I typed it and it was written exactly. Save they used a lower-case L. I'm having a hard time putting together why I would need A[L+S] in the if() return. I will work out trincot's example to test.

Comment: @KazRodgers Added the Wikipedia pseudocode too. There are differences, but it indeed shows consistency in the interpretation of the retuned index in both cases.